# Is there a way to browse inside .tar files in Windows, like you can with .zip files?

Tags: windows, zip, tar

Windows can easily browse inside .zip files, add and remove files, open files inside .zip.

Is there any optional Windows component I can install to do this with .tar files too?

Answer (score 0):

Windows has included [`tar.exe`](https://libarchive.org/) since [insider preview build 17063](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/) or [release version 1803](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows10v1803/). So just use it to create, extract or browse tar files

```
PS D:\> tar -cvf my.tar C:\Windows\*.exe # Create file
tar.exe: Removing leading drive letter from member names
a Windows/bfsvc.exe
a Windows/explorer.exe
a Windows/HelpPane.exe
a Windows/hh.exe
a Windows/notepad.exe
a Windows/regedit.exe
a Windows/RtkBtManServ.exe
a Windows/splwow64.exe
a Windows/winhlp32.exe
a Windows/write.exe

PS D:\> tar -tf my.tar # List content
Windows/bfsvc.exe
Windows/explorer.exe
Windows/HelpPane.exe
Windows/hh.exe
Windows/notepad.exe
Windows/regedit.exe
Windows/RtkBtManServ.exe
Windows/splwow64.exe
Windows/winhlp32.exe
Windows/write.exe
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: that's what's you asked. It's a built-in Windows component, no need to install anything. For GUI obviously you'll have to use some 3rd party solutions like 7z or Winrar

Comment: @Richard - You should [edit] your question in that case because as it's currently written this answer absolutely answers your question.